# ShellCheck warning: "Remove surrounding $() to avoid executing output. [SC2091]"

Tags: bash, shellcheck

I have the following set of commands in my script:

```
message="Secure copying file $remoteHost"
backupLogOutput "Info $message"
$(scp  "$file" "$remoteUser"@"$remoteHost":"$remotePath")  >> "$BACKUPLOG"
backupErrorHandler "$?" "$message"
```

ShellCheck is giving me the warning on the scp line (3):

> Remove surrounding $() to avoid executing output. [SC2091]

The script works. I do want to execute the output. Shall I ignore this warning or should the scp line be written in a different way?

Comment: the comments prevents for executing arbitrary output, indeed command between `$(..)` is like between backquotes, it is expanded to output, then the shell will split this output into command and arguments, try `$(echo "/bin/ls -l")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you actually do want to execute what `scp` outputs - it looks more like you simply want to copy a file:

```
scp  "$file" "$remoteUser"@"$remoteHost":"$remotePath"  >> "$BACKUPLOG"
```